# Положение элемента

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть ссылка, при наведении на которую появляется гифка.

```css
.poster {
  position: relative;
}

.gif {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -90px;
  left: 120px;
}

.poster:hover .gif {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
  <li>Email</li>
  <li>Skype</li>
  <li>Github</li>
  <li>vk</li>
  <li>Instagram</li>
  <li class="poster">
     <a href="#">Telegram</a>
       <div class="gif">
         <img src="https://i.gifer.com/iFc.gif"                      width="150" height="150">
       </div>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Абсолютным позиционированием и координатами задаю нужное положение гифки. Но при изменении размеров самой гифки (в html) она начинает смещаться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы независимо от размеров самой гифки, она появлялась в одном месте?

Comment: А зачем при hover еще раз absolute

Comment: Положение картинки никак не меняется из-за ее размеров. Ее левый верхний угол всегда будет в (-90px;120px) относительно элемента .poster

Answer (score 1):

Примените к гифке свойство `transform:translate(-50%,-50%)` - это заставит ее позиционироваться относительно собственного центра, а не верхнего левого угла. Разумеется, сами координаты `left/top` понадобится изменить. Если гифка поменяется и будет другой размер - ее центр останется на том же месте.